# Use gradient colors for pie chart in a range of two colors

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I would like to specify two colors and then produce a pie chart like this:

[image: Pie Chart]

In order to create the example, I used the [chart wizard](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard) but it appears to be deprecated and in the application that we create, we use [pie charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart). Is there any way to get that effect in pie charts?

Comment: did you find how to set colors with css ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible through standard configuration options for the new SVG pie charts.

However, CSS can be used to color the elements of the pie chart if you are in to that sort of thing. CSS can create gradients in various ways depending on browser, etc. For more information on that, see [this site](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/).

If you want to color a specific element of the pie chart, you can use something like the developer tools in Google Chrome to help track down a specific element, and recolor that element using CSS as above.

This will likely not work properly in IE (little does).

In general, however, the use of Gradients tends to just be eye candy, and actually makes the chart more difficult to read (it doesn't much matter for pie charts, which are [generally not the best choice](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/peltier-loves-pie/) of charts to begin with).