# Providing gradient colours for google chart api to draw pie chart

Tags: javascript, pie-chart, google-visualization

I am using google chart APIs to draw a pie chart on the page. This uses some default colors to draw the sectors of the pie. We have an option to provide our own colors to draw the pie chart like `colors:['red','#004411']` as suggested in https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart. Now I want to know how can I achieve some glassy effect by providing gradient colors to the APIs? Is there any way with which I cant achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14607708/use-gradient-colors-for-pie-chart-in-a-range-of-two-colors/14638874#14638874). This is what it says:

> It is not possible through standard configuration options for the new
>   SVG pie charts.
>
> However, CSS can be used to color the elements of the pie chart if you
>   are in to that sort of thing. CSS can create gradients in various ways
>   depending on browser, etc. For more information on that, see [this
>   site](http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/).
>
> If you want to color a specific element of the pie chart, you can use
>   something like the developer tools in Google Chrome to help track down
>   a specific element, and recolor that element using CSS as above.
>
> This will likely not work properly in IE (little does).
>
> In general, however, the use of Gradients tends to just be eye candy,
>   and actually makes the chart more difficult to read (it doesn't much
>   matter for pie charts, which are [generally not the best choice](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/peltier-loves-pie/) of
>   charts to begin with).